# video inside custom shaped border css

Tags: css, image, video, overlay, transparent

I'm not exactly sure about the correct term of what I'm trying to do.  But basically I am trying to set a video or flash.swf file inside a custom shaped border (the boarder isn't a perfect square) in the header of my website.

I've provided two pictures of what I mean. The first picture is what I want the page to look like when it first loads.  The second picture is what it should look like after the video or flash.swf file loads.

Notice how in the second picture there is an image that fits inside what I am calling  the boarder area. Again I do not know the proper term. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't even know where to begin to start.

Image 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhB6.jpg
Image 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ77g.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Set the wmode="opaque" in the embed / object tag. Then you can overlay the flash file with a png that is transparent in the area you want the flash visible.

the png must be positioned absolute that you can position it right via top/left and for the z-index.

Comment: If you do this though it'll be dependent on the controls for the video player NOT being inside the swf. (can't click through the PNG)

Comment: @mikevoermans - That is correct when you have a player with controls. If controls are needed I advice to work with 4 pngs that frame the flash to have no direct overlay above the controls.

Comment: would this be possible with a youtube video?

Comment: Generally it is possible with every element. It is only a question of the right architecture.